# partial derivative with respect to a vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

I encountered what I can only understand as a partial derivative with respect to a vector, used in a taylor series expansion, and would like to understand it better.

In the book I'm reading, $x(t)$ is an $n$-dimensional real vector, that is $x: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, and $u(t)$ is a real valued function, $t\in \mathbb{R}$.
We have the equation
$$
\dot{x} = f(x, u)
$$

The author writes that $f$ can be linearized around a stationary point, that is a point $(x_0, u_0)$ such that $f(x_0, u_0) = 0$:

> By looking at small deviations from $x_0$ and $u_0$
> $$
> x = x_0 + \Delta x\\  
> u = u_0 + \Delta u
>  $$
> we get with taylor expansion
> $$
> \dot{x} = \Delta \dot{x} = f(x_0 + \Delta x, u_0 + \Delta u) \approx \\
> f(x_0, u_0) + f_x(x_0, u_0)\Delta x + f_u(x_0, u_0)\Delta u
> $$
> where higher order terms in $\Delta x$ and $\Delta u$ are discarded. $f_x, f_u, h_x$ and $h_u$ denotes partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $u$. $f_x$ is a $n \times n$ matrix who's $i, j$ element is
> $$
> \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}f_i(x, u)
> $$
> where $f_i$ is the i:th row in $f$, and the corresponding is true for $f_u$.

I have never seen this type of partial derivative before, $f_x$ is a partial derivative with respect to $x$ and $x$ is a vector. I've only seen partial derivatives with respect to a real variable before, and the [wikipedia article on partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20partial%20derivative,variables%20are%20allowed%20to%20vary) does not seem to mention it. Not surprisingly I've also never seen this kind of taylor expansion, the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables) does not seem to use partial derivatives with respect to vectors, but I've never even worked with taylor series of several variables so I might be misunderstanding something.

I can't find much information about this, am I right that this is a special kind of partial derivatives and taylor series, and in that case does anyone know of some relatively easy to understand source of information?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here is a pdf answering your question in a more detailed fashion: [https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~csip/tirgul3_derivatives.pdf](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Ecsip/tirgul3_derivatives.pdf)

Now, how I would make sense of this, is well suppose that we have a vector $x$ with coordinates $(x_1,...,x_n)$. Then if one were to take partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f$, we would have to take derivatives of all possible coordinates, because recall that if you wish to evaluate the gradient of a function $f$, one would have to take partial derivatives depending on the number of variables $f$ takes. And so one could suppose the same thing for derivatives with respect to vectors. (I am sorry if this answer isn't clear. I am trying to explain things intuitively).

Maybe that was the authors intention. Namely, instead of righting down "blah-blah-blah partial derivative with respect to $x_i$" and so on and so forth, he just wrote partial derivative with respect to a vector $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure this answers the questions since in the question $f$ takes $n+1$ variables but $x$ is an $n$-dimensional vector? That is, the number of variables $f$ takes and the dimension of $x$ are not equal, as they are in your example.

Comment: Hey that is a little weird. But, you can take partial derivatives of $x,y$ say, but you don't $need$ to take the partial derivative of $z$, if $f$ is a function of $x,y,z$. (Unless you want to evaluate the gradient, in which case you have to evaluate all variables).